# Circular Convolution in Scilab

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am quite familiar with signal processing using Matlab. Now I am working in its open source alternative 'Scilab.' In Matlab, cconv() function is used to perform circular convolution between two sequences. I want to do circular convolution in Scilab. But I could not find an equivalent function for circular convolution in Scilab. Are there any other methods to perform circular convolution in Scilab (or, is there really a function for circular convolution in Scilab)?

Comment: This is a question about programming languages and software packages and as such is off-topic on dsp.SE.

Comment: If you are looking for a free alternative of matlab, then look to the GNU Octave. This program is much closer to Matlab. Many Matlab programs run without modification on Octave. This is not true for Scilab.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell about SciLab but if it is not implemented, you can always get the circular convolution by

IDFT(DFT(x1) * DFT(x2))

where x1 and x2 are your signal vectors and the multiplication is element-wise. If the signals have a different length, zeropad the shorter one to the length of the longer one. This assumes that you want to do circular convolution with a modulus equal to the length of the longer vector.